# Implementation of attribute moving to the selected group, selected set attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, attributes, admin-panel, attribute-set

Tell me how to implement attribute transfer to the desired group.

I have attribute set

```
            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $data = [
                'attribute_set_name' => 'Bed Attribute Set',
                'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
                'sort_order' => 200,
            ];
            $attributeSet->setData($data);
            $attributeSet->validate();
            $attributeSet->save();
            $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
            $attributeSet->save();
```

and attribute

```
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'Bed Left Image',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'YOUR ATTRIBUTE LABEL',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'input' => 'textarea',
                    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => true,
                    'source' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 19,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSet->getId(),
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => ''
                ]
            );
```

and I want to make it so that the created attribute was available only in this attribute set set and was added to the 'Content' group.

I add the attribute to the attribute set

```
'attribute_set_id' => $ attributeSet-> getId ()
```

and to the group

```
'Group' => 'Content'
```

but after that the attribute is available on all products and atribute set.

I tried not to add the attribute to the group, so that it would appear in my admin panel in unussigned attributes and I could add it manually to the desired group through the admin interface, and it worked as needed.
[image]

But now i'am need to do this programmatically, tell me how plz